# Automatically finding Thymeleaf templates with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I get Spring Boot and Thymeleaf to automatically find and map template files to be processed when accessed by the browser?

- `src/main/resources/templates/index.xhtml`
- `src/main/resources/templates/bar.xhtml`
- `src/main/resources/application.properties` contains `spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.xhtml`
- `FooController.java` contains `@RequestMapping("/foo")` and a `@PostMapping` method that returns `bar`

If I enter `http://localhost:8080/` in the browser, Thymeleaf processes and displays the `index.xhtml` page with no extra configuration needed. But `http://localhost:8080/index`, `http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml`, and `http://localhost:8080/index.html` all result in `404 Not Found`.

My `index` view does a `POST` to `foo`; `FooController` is activated and returns `bar`; and Thymeleaf processes and shows `bar.xhtml`, even though `bar.xhtml` isn't mapped anywhere in the configuration. Yet accessing `http://localhost:8080/bar`, `http://localhost:8080/bar.xhtml`, and `http://localhost:8080/bar.html` in a browser all result in `404 Not Found`.

- Why does `GET` `http://localhost:8080/` process the `index.xhtml` template, but `GET` `http://localhost:8080/index` does not?
- How can Thymleaf use `bar` as a view, but I cannot access `http://localhost:8080/bar` directly?
- How can I configure Thymeleaf so that I can add `src/main/resources/templates/example.xhtml` and have it processed automatically as a template that I can access via `http://localhost:8080/example` in the browser, with no explicit configuration specifically for the `example.xhtml` file?

If I absolutely have to configure controllers (see my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63874074)), is there a way that I can at least do this in some declarative file, outside of my code?

Comment: You will need to specify for each file a view-controller. If you want something else, you will have to build it yourself. In theory you could create a mapping for everything with an `@RequestMapping` and return void. Which would then use the `RequestToViewNameTranslator` to determine the name of the view. However this would also be dangerous as now anyone can access everything (even things they might nog see). You are basically opening up your application like that.

Comment: I realize this is a relatively old post but if you're still interested in an answer - my first question is "what's the motivation for wanting to access a 'template' without going through a controller?"  because that is basically just accessing a page that will never be different (i.e. not a template in the strictest sense)  I'll wait for a reply but I think you are trying to "shoehorn" Spring/Thymeleaf into doing what you think you want/need instead of maybe being open to learning how the view resolvers work and adjusting your "design" accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [*Spring in Action, Fifth Edition*](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fifth-edition), I can do something like this in a `@Configuration` class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`

```java
@Override
public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addViewController("/bar");
}
```

That will allow me to process `bar.xhtml` automatically. (I presume there is some default configuration `registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index")`, which is why my `index.xhtml` file is getting processed by accessing the root path.

And I can even use the following to automatically pick up any template:

```java
@Override
public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addViewController("/**");
}
```

Unfortunately this removes the mapping from `/` to `/index`, and also prevents accessing any static resources from `src/main/resources`. I'm not sure how to tell Thymeleaf to use a template if it can, and fall back to a static file if not.

Comment: I'm not sure about the static resources yet, but I would expect adding the following line to restore your access to /index: registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");    I'm also not sure if the order these lines appear might affect the end result.